# Visual Studio 2019 отключить автоматическую загрузку файлов проекта на сервер

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Помогите разобраться как в Visual Studio 2019 отключить автоматическую загрузку файлов проекта на сервер при их изменении? Уже все, что можно перерыл в настройках (до обновления все было норм.)

Answer (score -1):

Очень жаль, что ранее ни кто не ответил :)
Но на случай если кто-то столкнется с подобным:
Все дело было в дополнении PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2019 после его обновления проблема решилась!